# Angular 11 function called in every rendering loop

Tags: angular

this is my component html.

```
 <div *ngFor="let getData of activePage">
        <img [src]="svgsData(getData)" />
  </div>
```

How do I store that result `svgsData(getData)` into class member and use that in template? here how I am getting `svgsData` in typescript.

```
preview:any = [];
 activePage:any = [] 

    svgsData(image) {
      let base64string = btoa(image);
      return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64string}`
      );
    }



previewSvg() {
         this.systemComponent.fetchData().then(data =>{
       this.preview = data;
      this.activePage = this.preview.slice(0,this.pageSize);
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)  
});
```

I have tried this but that doesn't display the data:

```
previewSvg() {
         this.systemComponent.fetchData().then(data =>{
       this.preview = data; 
       this.svgsData(this.preview);
      this.activePage = this.preview.slice(0,this.pageSize);
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)  
});

 <div *ngFor="let getData of activePage">
        <img [src]="getData" />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly ill advised to use method callbacks in template e.g `svgsData(getData)`. Each time page is rendered, this method is called. Possibly hundreds of times.

Instead use pure pipes to run pipe each time prop is changed. A `| safe` pipe to clean and transform base64 string to content.

```
 <div *ngFor="let getData of activePage">
        <img [src]="getData | safe" />
  </div>
```

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe',
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(image: string) {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image);
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/creating-a-custom-pipe-in-angular-aho9ax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsafe.pipe.ts